# Nodejs https request certificate on mobile browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl

as the title stated, it works fine in desktop browser but not mobile browser.

i check on https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html

in mobile browser, especially Android Google Chrome (ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID) and its showing, the https missing its chains crt? Is there something missing in the **ssl_optio**n code?

my SSL provider is Comodo.

in NodeJS

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var ssl_options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync( 'ssl/' + 'mydomain.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync( 'ssl/' + 'mydomain.crt'),
    ca: fs.readFileSync( 'ssl/' + 'AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt'),
    ca: fs.readFileSync( 'ssl/' + 'COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt'),
    ca: fs.readFileSync( 'ssl/' + 'COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt')
};

var https = require('https').createServer( ssl_options, app);
```

Comment: You can't have more than one key with the same name in an object. Your `ca` keys are overwriting each other.

Comment: And it usually works in desktop browser because they have often cached the missing intermediates CA already.

Comment: it works in dekstop browser, but not mobile tho

Comment: Make `ca` an array: `ca: [fs.readFileSync( 'ssl/' + 'AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt'), fs.readFileSync( 'ssl/' + 'COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt'), fs.readFileSync( 'ssl/' + 'COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt')]`